# 32-bit vs. 4-bit in enum declaration

Tags: system-verilog

When I change the enumerated type variables from 4 bit to 32 bit, my error is appeased. I am wondering why I cannot keep it at 4 bit in this code.

Here are some pertinent snippets; I have deleted code related to non-pertinent variables:

Testbench:

```
module ALUtestbench;
  //Variable Declaration

  typedef enum {ADD = 32'b00, SUB = 32'b01, INV = 32'b10, RED = 32'b11} opcode_t;
  opcode_t opcode; //declare typed variable
  
  //Module Instance
  alu alu_inst(

   .opcode(opcode));
  
  initial begin
    opcode = opcode.first();
    #10;
    do
      begin
        $display(opcode);
        $display("For opcode %s the result is: %0h", opcode.name, result);
        opcode = opcode.next;
        #10;
      end
    while (opcode != opcode.first);
  end
endmodule
```

Design:

```
module ALU;
  input reg A [4:0];
  inout reg B [4:0];
  output reg C [4:0];
  initial begin
    always @ (*)
      begin
        case(opcode)
        ADD : C = A + B;
        SUB : C = A - B;
        INV : C = ~A;
        endcase
      end
          endmodule
```

At first, I had

```
  typedef enum {ADD = 4'b00, SUB = 4'b01, INV = 4'b10, RED = 4'b11} opcode_t;
  opcode_t opcode; //declare typed variable
```

and the compiler gave me the error:

> SystemVerilog requires the width of a sized constant in this context
> to match the width of the enumeration type.

I then changed to 32-bit, and the code now does not have this error. I am wondering why I needed to do that. Does the `case` statement reject anything less than 32-bit?

Answer (score 3):

If you do not explicitly declare a base type for an enumeration, the implicit datatype is `int`, which has a 32-bit width. Earlier versions of the SystemVerilog LRM also allowed you to use the label assignments form sized literals (i.e. `ADD = 32'b00`) to define the width explicitly instead of an explicit base type. But now the LRM only allows explicit base types. But it still has this rule in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595), section 6.19 Enumerations

> If the integer value expression is a sized literal constant, it shall be an error if the size is
> different from the enum base type, even if the value is within the representable range.

So either drop the size for the literals

```
typedef enum {ADD = 'b00, SUB = 'b01, INV = 'b10, RED = 'b11} opcode_t;
```

or write it as

```
typedef enum bit [3:0] {ADD = 4'b00, SUB = 4'b01, INV = 4'b10, RED = 4'b11} opcode_t;
```

Answer (score 2):

From IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 6.19 *Enumerations*:

> In the absence of a data type declaration, the default data type shall
> be **int**. Any other data type used with enumerated types shall require
> an explicit data type declaration.

Since `int` is 32-bit, you do not get an error when your constants are 32-bit.

If you want to use 4-bit constants, you need to explicitly declare your `enum` as 4-bit.  Change:

```
  typedef enum {ADD = 4'b00, SUB = 4'b01, INV = 4'b10, RED = 4'b11} opcode_t;
```

to:

```
  typedef enum bit [3:0] {ADD = 4'b00, SUB = 4'b01, INV = 4'b10, RED = 4'b11} opcode_t;
```

This has nothing to do with the `case` statement.